# How to check if Archive::Tar's write is successful?

Tags: perl, tar

I have a monthly Script running to archive files from past month. I'm using `Archive::Tar` to generate the archive. How can I check if calls to the `->write` method are successful?

Does the following work? I didn't manage to fail `$tar->write()` yet.

```
unless ($tar->write( $name . '.tar.xz', COMPRESS_XZ )) {
    die("cant write tar"); # or any other doings instead
}
```

Comment: What is `$tar` ? Please show complete script, see [mcve] for more information

Comment: Yes `$tar` is `Archive::Tar`

Comment: Please find a time to read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the code in your question will catch any error within `->write`.

The documentation of `Archive::Tar` does not specify what the return value of `write` is (except when no argument is provided, which isn't the case here). However, looking at [the code of the module](https://metacpan.org/dist/Archive-Tar/source/lib/Archive/Tar.pm#L1306-1450), `write` returns `undef` in case of an error and a true value in case of success:

- [`1` if it was writing to a file](https://metacpan.org/dist/Archive-Tar/source/lib/Archive/Tar.pm#L1437) (this is the case for the code in your question)
- [the written string if it was writing in a string](https://metacpan.org/dist/Archive-Tar/source/lib/Archive/Tar.pm#L1438-1439).

Note that if something goes wrong and `Archive::Tar` returns `undef`, then it will also print an error message (unless you set `$Archive::Tar::WARN` to `0` by doing `$Archive::Tar::WARN = 0`). If you want to do something specific depending on the error, you can access the error message using the [`->error`](https://perldoc.perl.org/Archive::Tar#$tar-%3Eerror(-%5B$BOOL%5D-)) method.

Comment: @NicoEggers This code would catch it, yes (so would the code in your question). For `WARN`, you need to do `$Archive::Tar::WARN = 0` (anywhere after `use Archive::Tar` and before the point where you want warnings to be disabled).

Comment: So   
`if ( $tar->write( $name . '.tar.xz', COMPRESS_XZ ) != 1 ) { 
die("cant write tar"); # or any other doings instead 
} `  
would catch it.   
You mentioned setting `$Archive::Tar::WARN` to `0`.  
Do i have to set it on my archive var `$tar`? Like `$tar::Tar::WARN = 0;`?  
Or do i have to change my `use Archive::Tar;`?